# Converting a mysql time format 00:00:00 to 00:00 AM/PM with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, format

I'm trying to convert a time format from my mysql DB. The time stored in there is 12:00:00 and i want it to be displayed as 12:00 PM. How would i do this?

Here is what i tried:

`$overdueTime = strftime('%I:%M %p', strtotime($settings_row[3]));`

With $settings_row[3] being the time.

thanks in advance ^.^

Comment: Is the time stored in the DB as a string?

Comment: That code should work. What problem are you having?

Comment: Your solution seems correct, how is it not?

Comment: Check that $settings_row[3] has the value that is supposed to have (a string formatted the way you mentioned). Otherwise I dont see why it wouldnt work.

Comment: The time is being stored as the mysql type 'time'. When i go and try to change the time with my new query and type in something like 7:00 AM and refresh the page, the time shown is 7:00 PM. How is this?

Comment: Do i need to change the sql data type to 'tinytext'? Then it would store the AM/PM text from the input field.

Comment: Just figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what was the solution? please post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Backend i converted it to military time:

`strftime('%H:%M:%S strtotime($_POST["overdueTime"]));`

Frontend i converted to 12 hour time:

`strftime('%I:%M %p', strtotime($settings_row[3]));`